# Paypal integration to Android

Tags: android, paypal

I am creating a app where I have to support users for online payment. For that purpose using the [Android Paypal Mobile SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/).

In the demo mode I was deal with sandbox feature of Paypal and its work perfectly.

Now, I want to move ahead in Live-Production mode.

So in this mode which parameters I need to change ?

I tried with changing

```
CONFIG_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL

CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;
```

But, thats not working for me and I'm getting different type of errors while trying to do payment.

So my question here is that what in `CONFIG_CLIENT_ID` what I need to put ?
and how can I obtain its value ?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Are you working with Adaptive Payments or REST?

Comment: SYSTEM ERROR. & i am working Adaptive Payments

Comment: I am also getting same issues.
CONFIG_CLIENT_ID, in this which value i need to put ?

Answer (score 2):

This will help resolving your error.

```
CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using the latest version of the SDK - you should.  (CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL is no longer needed)

To shift to live, you should only need to change the CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT to use the production value, and CONFIG_CLIENT_ID to the Live credentials' `Client ID` on https://developer.paypal.com.

Comment: Hi Am also plan to integrate Pay Pal in to Android APP for that am using Latest Pay Pal Android SDK.:http://mayuran26.blogspot.in/2014/09/integrate-paypal-account-to-your.html am fallowing this link.SandBox is Ok Now plan to integrate Live account details how can i integrate and coming to sand box when i create an app default sand box account is setted.how can i integrate  my live account details and all.I need to integrate Pay pal Indian Business Account Please provide some help.